# Is it possible to set up auto-import in WebStorm without double dots?

Tags: typescript, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I want in auto-import something like `modules/Component/components/MyComponent` instead of `../MyComponent`.

Is it possible to do in WebStorm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `modules/Component/...` path is a path from the project root (folder where `tsconfig.json` is located, or the root specified with `baseurl`), enabling **Use paths relative to tsconfig.json** in **Settings | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript | Imports** should be enough. Otherwise, you need specifying [path mappings](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) in the `tsconfig.json`